# Who manages interlal application intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I was studying some sample examples for Android and one of them got me really curious:
 the NoteList (or Notepad) example application - [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html)

My question is: Is there any way to make a NoteList shortcut, that always starts the application with its 'Editor' activity, for example.  [of course if the creator of that 'third-party' application intended to make it possible by describing the entry points of its application in a proper way in the manifest file. I do not intent to create malware.]

in other words:

Can a third-party application (like the one I wish to make :) ) to get to internal application intents {i.e. action, activity, data} or this is handled by Android and no one else?

What gave the idea that this is possible was the following case:
I opened NoteList, created a few note, and when I was editing the title of one of the notes - I pressed HOME, when I clicked on the icon of NoteList I got the exact same state of the application - editing the title of the note.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has nothing to do with the other. That means that reopen an activity which was paused or killed with a data restoring logic just restores the last state. This is what happened in your example.

Now what you mean I guess is if there is a way to tell Android that you application can do a certain thing thus it should be shown as an option in the [action chooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER). Yes that is possible through intent filters.

The [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) reference page might also be very informative for you.

Comment: @karla actually it's called the action chooser or activity chooser which get called when a more than one activity on your device could handle a certain action an user might want to do. I've edited my answer with some links for you.